# Memory and CPU ressource allocation of Python-instances with pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Regarding *pySpark* in cluster-mode, I understood that on each worker-node executors are launched in *Java Virtual Machiens (JVMs)* and they are connected via pipes to Python-instances using *Py4J*.

However, I still need further clarification on the ressources (CPU + Memory) the Python-instances can use respectively how this can be regulated. Lets assume I have a setup like this with dynamic ressource allocation:

```
echo Starting $1...
./spark-submit \
    --name "test" \
    --executor-memory 24g \
    --executor-cores 5 \
    --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=100" \
    --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1" \
    --driver-memory 24g \
    --driver-cores 5 \
    /home/foo/bar/test.py
```

**This results in three questions:**

1. Is the Python-instance launched as normal process on the worker-node (meaning in Linux it gets a PID etc.) or also in a JVM?
2. Is the Python-instance also restricted to the executor-memory or has it access to all ressources on the node like a normal Python-environment?
3. If 2. applies: How can I restrict that with my Spark-settings?

Comment: 1 - yes, 2 - the latter one, 3 - there is no such mechanism built-in into Spark

Comment: Short and to the point - Kudos and thanks :)